# FB Marketing API - Outbound_clicks not returned

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to get insight data for Ads using the FB marketing API.

I notice that the "Outbound_Clicks" field is not returned when I include breakdowns=Description_Asset in my API call. When I remove breakdowns=Description_Asset, the call returns "Outbound_Clicks".

Is there something that prevents getting both the description_asset breakdown and outbound_click field or am I doing something wrong? Here's my API call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/<AD_ID>/insights?fields=account_id,account_name,actions,action_values,ad_id,ad_name,adset_id,adset_name,buying_type,campaign_id,campaign_name,clicks,conversions,cpp,cpm,date_start,frequency,impressions,reach,spend,outbound_clicks&level=ad&breakdowns=description_asset`